# how to extract data from API using Talend

Tags: database, postgresql, linkedin-api, talend

i am new with talend and i want to know how to do to extract data from API using Talend  and send the results to the database PostgreSQL

I want to know what are the components that I suppose to use it and how to configure it
PS: I am trying to extract data from LinkedinAPI  and how to send it to the data base PostgreSQL

Comment: So, having read all the relevant documentation, what have you tried and what specific issue are you facing?

Comment: i suggest you to use Postman first and see the result  then once your api call is fine , You can use two components to make the api call tRest and tRestClient then link the component with a tExtractJsonFields if the output is json if the output is xml  you can use textractxmlfield -> then plug a tLogRow to see the result ,

Comment: I Have already  used Postman and it's working fine but  now I want to know how to configure the tREST component  to start sending HTTP requests to the Linkedin API

Comment: show us the postman call , i will give you the correct configuration